# trying to make math game that repeatedly asks random questions and if you get it right the score goes up one point

Tags: vb.net

trying to make math game that repeatedly asks random questions and if you get it right the score goes up one point.
here is my code so far.

```
Sub Main()
        Randomize()
        Dim RandomNum As New Random

        Dim num1, num2, operation, score As Integer
        Dim output As String
        Dim correctAnswer As Single

        num1 = RandomNum.Next(1, 5)
        num2 = RandomNum.Next(1, 5)
        operation = RandomNum.Next(1, 4)

        If (operation = 1) Then
            output = " + "
            correctAnswer = num1 + num2
        ElseIf (operation = 2) Then
            output = " - "
            correctAnswer = num1 - num2
        ElseIf (operation = 3) Then
            output = " * "
            correctAnswer = num1 * num2
        Else
            output = " / "
            correctAnswer = num1 / num2
        End If

        While True
            Console.WriteLine("What is " & num1 & output & num2 & "?")
            If Console.ReadLine = correctAnswer Then
                score = score + 1
                Console.WriteLine("The correct answer is " & correctAnswer)
                Console.WriteLine("Your score is " & score)
                Console.ReadLine()
            Else
                score = score - 1
                Console.WriteLine("The correct answer is " & correctAnswer)
                Console.WriteLine("Your score is " & score)
                Console.ReadLine()
            End If

        End While

End Sub
```

i cant seem to be able to get a new question after the user answers the first

Comment: You need to put all the logic that calculates the next answer in a Sub that you call inside the loop. Also you need to make the variable involved visible both to the new Sub and into the main loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the amount of operations done, and move your operation condition logic in your `While` loop. Something like this :

```
Sub Main()
    Randomize()

    Dim RandomNum As New Random

    Dim num1, num2, operation, score As Integer
    Dim output As String
    Dim correctAnswer As Single

    operation = 1

    While True
        num1 = RandomNum.Next(1, 5)
        num2 = RandomNum.Next(1, 5)

        If (operation = 1) Then
            output = " + "
            correctAnswer = num1 + num2
        ElseIf (operation = 2) Then
            output = " - "
            correctAnswer = num1 - num2
        ElseIf (operation = 3) Then
            output = " * "
            correctAnswer = num1 * num2
        Else
            output = " / "
            correctAnswer = num1 / num2
        End If

        Console.WriteLine("What is " & num1 & output & num2 & "?")
        If Console.ReadLine = correctAnswer Then
            score = score + 1
            Console.WriteLine("The correct answer is " & correctAnswer)
            Console.WriteLine("Your score is " & score)
            Console.ReadLine()
        Else
            score = score - 1
            Console.WriteLine("The correct answer is " & correctAnswer)
            Console.WriteLine("Your score is " & score)
            Console.ReadLine()
        End If

        operation = operation + 1
        If operation = 5 Then ' Basically after all operations have been executed
            Console.WriteLine("You have finished the Math Test!")
            Console.WriteLine("Your final score is " & score)
            Console.ReadLine()
            Environment.Exit(0)
        End If


    End While

End Sub
```

Works as expected. Note that the numbers are randomized each time now to make it better (and I guess that's what you wanted to happen). The first operation is also not randomized anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you try stepping through your code, you'll see that the while loop does not re-evaluate the random generator to get another question. You need to move the while true statement above where you are fetching the next random question.